# How to diagnose audio drop outs?

Tags: windows, audio

My usual troubleshooting process has reached an impasse.

Occasionally, the audio will just cut out for a half second. This feels exactly like buffering lag (and it's usually YouTube), but nothing else is buffering, and it happens with non-streamed sources, AND my system shouldn't be straining to play back HD video with sound.

I've systematically tested each piece of hardware in the chain, and confirmed that something about my PC (as opposed to speakers or DAC) is causing occasional cuts in audio, from most (but not all) sources.

My question is more about a general approach, than this problem in particular.

I've uninstalled and updated the audio drivers, I've checked for general latency issues, and I've reproduced the issue with different hardware (on the same system).

So, the real question is: Where do I look to find out what's going wrong with the audio?
The Event Viewer doesn't show any errors. The Device Manager says the hardware is working properly. None of my resources are even close to being taxed...

I'm at a loss for where I could look for an error log, or what I could test, to find out what KIND of problem I'm even experiencing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Still no comprehensive guide for diagnosing audio issues in a Windows environment, but this particular issue was caused by insufficient power supply to the DAC and an old USB driver.